# Updating Braintree Default Payment

Tags: ios, braintree

In the seemingly never-ending quest to understand Braintree's obfuscated documentation, I ended up creating my own update UI with a list of `BTPaymentMethod`

The Braintree docs say to update a payment method with a token (which I see in my online sandbox vault). How do I retrieve an indivdual customers card token to update?

I'm using `-[BTClient fetchPaymentMethodsWithSuccess:failure:]`, which returns `BTPaymentMethod`which only has the`payment_nonce` property. Trying to update with this property return an error `CVV is required.`

```
def update_payment_default
@customer = Customer.where(id: params[:id]).first
if @customer.present?
  @string = "customer_" + @customer.id.to_s
  result = Braintree::Customer.update(
      "my_customer_id"
      :credit_card => {
          :payment_method_nonce => params[:payment_method_nonce],
          :options => {
              :make_default => true
          }
      }
  )
  if result.success?
    respond_to do |format|
      msg = {:status => "SUCCESS", :message => "Updated payment payment method"}
      format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      msg = {:status => "FAILED", :message =>  result.errors}
      format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
    end
  end
end
```